# C# how to clone List of Lists

Tags: c#, clone

I have class Attribut and Values. I don't know how to clone item Value in list.

```
public class Attribut : ICloneable
{
    public Attribut()
    { }

    public Attribut(List<Values> value)
    {
        this.Values = value;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

   //other members



    List<Values> values = new List<Values>();y

    public List<Values> Values
    {
        get { return values; }
        set { values = value; }
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class Values : ICloneable
{
    public Values()
    {
    }

    public Values(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public Values(string name, int count)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Count = count;
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    string name;

    int count = 0;



    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

I have problem to clone Values when I call this method(attrList) is global variable)
when I add new value into list, the same value is added also in the attrList.

```
private List<Attribut> getSelectedColumns()
    {
        List<Attribut> list = new List<Attribut>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].Checked == true)
            {
                list.Add((Attribut)attrList[i].Clone());
                for(int j= 0; j < attrList[i].Values.Count;j++)
                {
                    list[j].Values.Add((Values)attrList[i].Values[j].Clone());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is your `Clone` method defined?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I can't imagine it should be this hard.

Comment: Method is defined inside classes look code. I have plugin aplication and I need send metada to plugin.In attrList<t> are all metadata and in list<t> are selected metadata.And I work with this list in plugins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that first of all you need to understand differences between **shallow copy** and **deep copy**.

In short, first one just copies references (thus making two objects which references the same lists), while second one creates 'true copy'.

So, `MemberwiseClone` creates **shallow copy**, while it seems you need **deep copy**.

In most cases **deep copy** requires custom programming, as only you know how properly create different objects (which constructors to use, which properties to copy, which resources to allocate etc).

For example, if your object holds a handler to file, it's up to you and your logic to decide if you need to share this file between cloned objects, or to actually clone the files themselves.

So in your case most probably deep copy for `List<Value>` should look like this one:

```
    public object Clone()
    {
        var result = (Attribut)MemberwiseClone();
        result.values = values.Select(x => (Values)x.Clone()).ToList();
        return result;
    }
```

Be sure to reflect this deep copy logic for all lists / objects you don't want to share between clones.